# Apache winnt_accept: getsockname error

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am using wampserver 2. While setting up the things suddenly this error comes in my apache_error.log

```
(OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
```

Everything works fine on domains without sub-domain.

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/www/mainsite"
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    <Directory "D:/www/mainsite">       
        Options -Indexes
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/www/mainsite"
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    <Directory "D:/www/mainsite">       
        Options -Indexes
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/www/myapp"
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    <Directory "D:/www/myapp">
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        Options -Indexes
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can access **http://mydomain.com** but not **http://www.mydomain.com** neither **user1.mydomain.com** etc.

Answer (score 2):

I found something that solved it, I am still investigating cause...

To get rid of this error:
CODE: SELECT ALL
(OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. : winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
by following these instruction to reset winsock:

You need a command prompt (console) window.
Click on start>run>
Type:
cmd.exe
Type exactly:

netsh winsock RESET

Comment: C:\>netsh winsock reset
Sucessfully reset the Winsock Catalog.
You must restart the computer in order to complete the reset.