# Wamp is online but localhost keeps loading

Tags: apache, wamp

I installed wamp 2.4 in my system. But it is not loading localhost. It keeps loading and loading in firefox.
In apache errors log, i found the following error
    `[Sat Nov 30 20:11:44.232540 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 2592:tid 1508] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the problem.

If you ever get the following error while executing:

> `netsh winsock reset`
>
> The following helper DLL cannot be loaded: WSHELPER.DLL
>   The following command was not found: winsock reset

It means that your PC is badly attacked by trojans. Scan full system with an antivirus to confirm. Removing virus is the only way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [Wampserver forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,87151,87179)

> Try editing your c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts  (make sure to
>   create a backup)
>
> It should contain only one reference to "localhost"
>
> and that should read
>
> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> if you see a line like this ::1 localhost
>
> comment it out like so
>    #::1 localhost
>
> Reboot.
>
> Start wamp and try again.

Also look at this question ..
[Apache winnt_accept: getsockname error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351732/apache-winnt-accept-getsockname-error)

Comment: Did as you said, but still localhost is loading and loading

Comment: do you any errors in log file? Also make sure you don't have IIS running on the same server..it uses port 80 too

Comment: I am having only this error in apache error log, which keeps repeating while attempting to browse localhost. I checked if the port is used by others in command port, but it is only used by wamp. The fact is that this error came first when i reinstalled wamp. My first installation was working fine.
[Sat Nov 30 20:11:44.232540 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 2592:tid 1508] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?`

Comment: i googled around for the error but found the same..did you try the solution in the linked answer also?

Comment: Yes, but when i try to execute `netsh winsock reset` in command prompt, it is showing error like
Could not load WSHELPER.DLL

Comment: did you run the command prompt as admin? and try the command?

Comment: Also you can try changing the default apache port from wamp..change it to something like 8081  and try to restart wamp. check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp .. also you can download and run this fix http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9662461

Comment: Yes i run it as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close other servers working like teamviewer for example.

I have also read that sometimes even skype make conflict with wamp.

So try again but before you open wamp close every other app using internet and is loading when windows starting.

Probably an app listening to the same port with your server.

Or you can try to change the port (from 80 change it to 8080 or something else) but then remember to load  localhost : 8080/

Comment: I'm not using IIS,skype...but i changed port to 8383 and 8080, but still the loading continues